# android,firebase - update android view on firebase value change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'am making an android application that communicates with firebase.

My problem is tough I'am able to read the value of a child element, am not able to see the updated value of the child element when I update it on the database.

This is my JAVA code:

```
public class fireDemo extends AppCompatActivity {

   public interface blaze
   {
       // Write a message to the database
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("input");
   }
   private TextView display;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_demo);

       display = findViewById(R.id.display);

       myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               String change = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
               display.setText(change);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
   }
}
```

Using this I'am able to see the value in child element but, am not able to see the updated value when I update it in firebase online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` It will give you values once.

Use `addValueEventListener`, it will be called whenever there is any change in value.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

}
```